# General term of $x_{n+1} = 1 - a\left(1-\frac{b}{1-(1-b)^{n+1}(1-\frac{1}{c})}\right)(1-x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to know whether it is possible to give the general term of a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ defined inductively by

$$x_{n+1} = 1 - a\left(1-\frac{b}{1-(1-b)^{n+1}(1-\frac{1}{c})}\right)(1-x_n),$$

with $a,b,c\in(0,1)$.

Comment: What is the context of the problem, do you really need a closed form of the recurrence? Also do you know the initial conditions for this recurrence? If $n\in\Bbb N$ then what is the value of $x_1$

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange $x_{n+1}$ expression:

$\dfrac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_n-1} = a\left(\dfrac{1-b-c'(1-b)^{n+1}}{1-c'(1-b)^{n+1}}\right)=a(1-b)\left(\dfrac{1-c'(1-b)^{n}}{1-c'(1-b)^{n+1}}\right)\tag1$

where $c'=1-\frac{1}{c}$

Let $u_n={1-c'(1-b)^{n}}\tag2$

We get

$\dfrac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_n-1} =a(1-b)\dfrac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}\tag3$

Viz.

$\dfrac{(x_{n+1}-1)}{x_n-1} \dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} =a(1-b)$

$\dfrac{(x_{n}-1)}{x_{n-1}-1} \dfrac{u_{n}}{u_{n-1}} =a(1-b)$

.

.

.

$\dfrac{(x_{2}-1)}{x_{1}-1} \dfrac{u_{2}}{u_{1}} =a(1-b)$

Multiplying both sides from 1 to n we have:

$\dfrac{(x_{n+1}-1)}{x_{1}-1} \dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_{1}} =a^n(1-b)^n\tag4$

Express $x_{n+1}$ which results the explicit formula:

$x_{n+1}=1+(x_1-1)a^n(1-b)^n\frac{1-c'(1-b)}{1-c'(1-b)^{n+1}}\tag5$

Comment: Nice approach. Should't the denominator in the last expression be $1 - c\prime(1-b)^{n+1}$? You are dividing both sides by $u_{n+1}$ which is defined as: $u_{n+1} = 1 - c\prime(1-b)^{n+1}$

Comment: @roman, yes you are right, it could be a copy-paste error. Let me edit it. Thanks.